# Most efficient way to create fill rectangles in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

Given a list of coordinates that represent a rectangle in a grid (e.g. the upper-left and lower-right coordinate), which would be the most efficient way to fill a binary NumPy array with ones in the place of that rectangles?

The simple way would be to do a for loop such as

```py
arr = np.zeros((w, h))
for x1, y1, x2, y2 in coordinates:
    arr[x1:x2, y1:y2] = True
```

where coordinates is something like `[(x_11, y_11, x_22, y_22), ..., (x_n1, y_n1, x_n2, y_n2)]`

However, I want to try to avoid it, as it is one of the advantages of using vectorial inner NumPy operations. I have tried the `logical_and` but it seems that it works for a single rectangle or condition. How could I do it in a more "numpy" way?

The resulting image would be something like this for 2 rectangles:

[image: Example image]

Comment: You could use [.meshgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) or maybe [.mgrid](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) to *make* all the indices for an [Index array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) but if your coordinates are in a Python list or tuple you are going to have to iterate over them anyway so there is no advantage - might as well leave it as-is. Unless you have a Huge number of indices your for loop should be pretty fast. What is `coordinates` your [mre] should include an example of it

Answer (score 3):

Let say (1,1) are the upper-left coordinates of the rectangle,
and (5,4) the lower-right.
Then

```
arr = np.zeros((10, 10))
arr[1:5, 1:4] = 1
```

returns

```
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Comment: I know, this is what I did in the for loop. However, what I want is to do it vecorized for all the rectangles avoiding the loop