# Slicing a NDarray : TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I would like to be able to slide a Ndarray with some beginning and end indexes, a little bit like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71422564/3d-volume-slicing-typeerror-only-integer-scalar-arrays-can-be-converted-to-a-s) post. However I cannot find ways to make it work :

```
import numpy as np

mask = - np.ones((3, 5))

num_features = 4

beginning = np.zeros((3, num_features), dtype=int)
end = np.ones((3, num_features), dtype=int) * 3 

for i in range(num_features):
    mask[0, beginning[:, i]:end[:, i]] = 1

print(mask)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_25800/2724952886.py in <module>
      9 
     10 for i in range(num_features):
---> 11     mask[:, beginning[:, i]:end[:, i]] = False
     12 
     13 print(mask)

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Thanks !

Comment: `beginning[:, i]` is a (3,) array.  `slice` can only take single numbers.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want. Do you want to specify different slices for each item in your first dimension?

Comment: @hpaulj so how can it be done, I have very large arrays to work with and I can't resolve to use for loops

Comment: @MatthiasMertens I would like to have arrays that delimitates the beginning and the ends of slices. in the first dimension yes

Comment: @MatthiasMertens in the application, I will have a large 2D grid and will fill some part of the grid with rectangles using x1, x2, y1 and y2 values, very similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66477295/most-efficient-way-to-create-fill-rectangles-in-numpy

Comment: I guess you could do one pass like `mask[y1:y2, x1:x2]` for each rectangle. Otherwise you could maybe use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)? No idea if its fast. You need to benchmark yourself.